# Why does this simple loop produce a "jittery" print?

Tags: python, loops, infinite-loop

I'm just learning Python and I have tried this simple loop based on [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://www.learnpythonthehardway.org/book/chapter10.html). With my basic understanding, this should keep printing "Hello", one letter at a time at the same position. This seems to be the case, but the print is not fluid, it doesn't spend the same amount of time on each character; some go very fast, and then it seems to get stuck for one or two seconds on one.

Can you explain why?

```
while True:
    for i in ["H","e","l","l","o"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

Comment: Your system has to do other things too and that can disrupt the printing frequencies. Then there are buffers and buffer flushes and task switches, etc.

Comment: Actually I think it is just 'an illusion' because you have to 'l's and it basically stays more on the screen

Comment: Try simply removing your `while true`, it should be much faster.

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë: Then it'll be done after one run through the `for` loop; that loop is fast enough as it is, you'd not see the patterns at all.

Comment: @HerrActress I'm pretty sure that's not the case. I've tried with different words and combinations.

Comment: @Martijn: Thanks, I guess you refer to the same thing as njzk2.

Comment: Yes, njzk2's answer is basically the same as my comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you have any input on my comment to his answer? Just trying to make this as complete as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are running an infinite loop with very little work done in it, and most of it being printing. The bottleneck of such an application is how fast your output can be integrated in your running environment (you console).

There are various buffers involved, and the system can also schedule other processes and therefore pause your app for a few cycles.

Comment: Thanks. So it is my system that pauses the application every once in a while. Would that still happen if it were performing some hard computation? Also, could I eliminate this pause by giving the application a higher priority?

Comment: This happens for all processes, but with rapidly changing I/O is just visible more. No, you cannot eliminate the pausing unless you re-programmed this for a real-time OS instead; a multi-tasking OS will always introduce *some* delays.